# How can I restore my extensions?

Tags: firefox, upgrade, browser-addons

Something weird happened with my FireFox install (probably related to failed attempted upgrade but not sure?); and it crashed, restarted and gave me 2 options: start in safe mode or "refresh".

I chose "Refresh", and after much chugging along, it came up sans any of my previously installed add-ons.

Good news 1: my previous profile seems intact, except for add-ons. Bookmarks, history etc...

Good news 2: The profile **still has `extensions.json`** file that looks like it has my prior extensions!

Bad news: `extensions` directory is empty, and no add-ons show as installed.

## Is there a way for me to restore my previous extensions, using the json config file?

I would like to retain extension data if possible, assuming it didn't get wiped out (my sessions data seems to still be available in sessionstore-backups, for example )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also happened to me once to get that dialog of starting in safe mode or refresh, and I just killed `firefox.exe` and launched it again and everything
returned to normal (I might have also rebooted).

The refresh should have left on your desktop a folder named "Old Firefox Data", which should contain everything including your extensions.
But if that extensions folder is empty, and you know the names of the
extensions, you will need to reinstall them one-by-one from the
[Add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) page.

In the future, I suggest to set up your account with Mozilla and use
the sync feature. This will auto-install your extensions on any device
running Firefox once you logon and start syncing.

For more information see [How do I set up Sync on my computer?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer)

Comment: "Old Firefox Data" was the ticket (ironically I found it before you posted your answer :)